# how to get state right after state change in react hooks

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hi Everyone I am unable to get current state after setting up the state. I am calling a function Where I am passing that state but I am always getting default state in that function.
this is my State-

```
const [currentValue , setCurrentValue] = useState(one[0]); // where one[0] is string "Test"
```

this is my onchange function -

```
const getTest = useCallback((newValue:string) => {
 setCurrentValue({
    label:newValue,
    value:newValue
});
  getCurrentValue(currentValue.value);
  getSortOrder()
}, [])
```

this is my getSortOrder function -

```
const getSortOrder  =() => {
console.log(currentValue);
}
```

I am not getting updated state in getSortOrder function & getCurrentValue function. But yes If I am trying to console the state in render then it is showing me updated state but in function it is not updating. How can I achieve the updated state in both functions ?

Comment: State changes are asynchronous, you can't use/print values directly after settings them. You should pass `newValue` into ``getCurrentValue` and `getSortOrder`, it depends on what kind of functionality you want but it might be better of putting that inside a `useEffect` and making the state value a dependency

Comment: @Jayce444 How can we do it using useEffect. Can you put some code here related to it ?

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question correctly then this might help:

```
const getTest = useCallback((newValue:string) => {
 setCurrentValue({
    label:newValue,
    value:newValue
});
//try this code doing in useEffect
}, [])       

 useEffect(() => {
           getCurrentValue(currentValue.value);
           getSortOrder()
      },[currentValue]); //Everytime currentValue changes it will give new state
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the 'setCurrentValue' function is an asynchronous function and the state is updated after both the functions 'getCurrentValue' and 'getSortOrder' have finished their execution.

One easy solution will be to pass the parameter 'newValue' to both the functions like this :

```
    const getTest = useCallback((newValue:string) => {
           setCurrentValue({
              label:newValue,
              value:newValue
             });
           getCurrentValue(newValue);
           getSortOrder(newValue)
     }, [])


     const getSortOrder  =(newValue) => {
        console.log(newValue);
      }
```

Or you can use the 'useEffect' functionality to trigger the functions after the value of the state has been updated like this :

```
    const getTest = useCallback((newValue:string) => {
       setCurrentValue({
          label:newValue,
          value:newValue
         });
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
      getCurrentValue();
      getSortOrder()
    },[currentValue]);
```

Comment: We can not pass callBack just after setCurrentValue. It is saying expected 1 argument but got 2.

Comment: Apparently you can't use callback in case of statehooks and useEffect is the equivalent to the functionality provided with setState(in case of class component). Sorry i will update my answer @AnuragMishra

Comment: Please update your answer so that I can have better idea. Thanks

Comment: Consider useEffect as a lifecycle method which gets called once the state is updated.